# Login no Facebook - PHP

Tags: php, facebook, login, oauth

Colegas, estou tentando inserir a opção de LOGIN pelo Facebook em minha aplicação de teste (Local Host), porém está exibindo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minhas configurações estão da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já fiz diversas alterações e até agora nada. Vendo alguns vídeos no Youtube, deixa a entender que como a maioria deles já fazem um tempo estão desatualizados, então suas configurações não são as mesmas.

Segue abaixo o link com os arquivos que estou utilizando:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lpQy3bzPsGlZa9Ka0FOnsnrzT46gYewa

OBS.: Retirei o meu 'app_id' e 'app_secret' apenas por ser estar compartilhando o meu arquivo, mas o atual está preenchido corretamente.

Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Você provavelmente não está definindo a mesma `url` de redirecionamento no método `getLoginUrl()`.

Comment: E em que arquivo está localizado esse método para que eu possa fazer essa alteração?

Comment: Você tem que postar o seu código para que possamos verificar onde está essa falha e verificar se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Editei a pergunta acrescentando o link com meus arquivos (peguei um exemplo simples que o próprio Facebook disponibiliza)

Comment: No arquivo `login.php` você deve alterar `https://example.com/fb-callback.php` para a URL que você cadastrou em `URIs de redirecionamento do OAuth Válidos`

Comment: De fato eu havia esquecido de alterar esse arquivo, fiz a alteração mas ainda persiste no erro. Se não for pedir muito, você poderia tentar fazer algo simples e testar você mesmo? Porque eu estou vendo diversas pessoas com o mesmo problema, daí se alguém mais experiente testar e funcionar é falha nossa, caso contrário eu creio que seja algum problema com a API do Facebook mesmo...

Comment: Não é erro do SDK, testei agora com seu código (`login.php`) e está tudo OK. (Apenas adicionei a mesma URL que cadastrei no Facebook Developer)

Comment: Caramba, mas o meu está com a mesma URL 'https://epcriacao.com/fb-callback.php' ... Você poderia me enviar um link com print's da sua tela de Configuração Básica e a tela de configuração de  Login do Facebook por favor? Obrigado pela atenção que tem me dado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como eu disse nos comentários da pergunta, você **deve** utilizar **a mesma url (literalmente)** da configuração *URIs de redirecionamento do OAuth Válidos* quando chamar o método *getLoginUrl*

- Se você usar **https** em uma URL, deverá utilizar na outra;
- Se você **não** usar **www** em uma URL, você **não** deverá utilizar na outra;
- Se você utilizar um arquivo *facebook-callback.php* em uma url, você deverá utilizar na outra;
- Não use URL semelhante, use a mesma.

Se você usar https://epcriacao.com/fb-callback.php no método `getLoginUrl`, você **deve** usar https://epcriacao.com/fb-callback.php na configuração `URIs de redirecionamento do OAuth válidos`

Se você colocar um caractere a mais ou a menos, vai dá erro.

**PHP:**

```
session_start();

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
  'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

echo $helper->getLoginUrl("https://www.meu-site-de-exemplo.com/facebook-callback.php", ["email"]);
```

**Configuração:**
[image: Configuração da URL de retorno no Facebook Developer]

**URL Gerada:**

`https://www.facebook.com/v2.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&state=<STATE>&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.6.1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.meu-site-de-exemplo.com%2Ffacebook-callback.php&scope=email`

**Resultado da URL Gerada:**
[image: Resultado da URL Gerada]

**facebook-callback.php**

```
session_start();

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => 'APP_ID',
  'app_secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}
```

**Capturando os dados do Usuário:**

```
$me = $fb->get("/me?fields=id,name,email", $accessToken);
$user = $me->getGraphUser();
echo $user["email"];
```

Comment: Entendi! Realmente eu estava digitando errado um caractere... Porém eu fiz a correção e agora ele está me retornando a seguinte mensagem de erro: Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.

Comment: Utilize `session_start();` na primeira linha dos arquivos `login.php` e `fb-callback.php`

Comment: Nada também... Eu havia pesquisado a respeito dessa mensagem de erro e vi realmente um post falando sobre isso, mas aqui não funcionou. Você usou exatamente o arquivo que eu compartilhei? Porque ele não tinha a session_start()

Comment: Eu não utilizei session no código porque não cheguei a testar o recebimento o "accessToken", pois não era o erro do post. Mas verifiquei agora e funcionou quando adicionei o session_start(); Ps.: Na documentação tem informando que é devido CSRF. Atualizei minha resposta

Comment: O meu continua com a mesma mensagem de erro. Poderia postar o link dos seus arquivos por favor?

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!Qp91xZSR!R8pkIQUaCjAV-y-uADc8U9PtqDr08t75KzAh4tpi-2g

Comment: Opa, testei aqui os meus códigos anteriores e consegui. No seu também, mas utilizando o seu, em qual variável eu consigo obter o e-mail de login ?

Comment: @EduardoPereira editei minha resposta. Adicionei como capturar os dados do usuário.

Comment: Agora sim, você é o cara! Muitíssimo obrigado por toda atenção e dedicação. Problema solucionado \o/