# Login Facekook - PHP

Tags: php, login, facebook-sdk

Eu acredito estar tudo certo nas configurações do Aplicativo, alguém já passou por isso e conseguiu resolver ?

[image: Erro]

Nas minhas configurações está assim

[image: Configurações Facebook]

Comment: Já tentou isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/267526/99718 ?

Comment: O que seria isso !?